# Multidimensional Array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I can't seem to get anything to go into my ['count'] key. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<script>
        $.getJSON( "someAddress", function( data ) {
            $( ".result" ).html( data );
            var totalUse    =   new Array();
            var totalLen    =   data.stats.length;
            for(x = 0; x < totalLen; x++){
                var user    =   data.stats[x].userId;
                if(totalUse.indexOf(user) > -1){ // yes it does have it
                    totalUse[user]["count"] += data.stats[x].count;
                }else{
                    totalUse[user]          =   data.stats[x].userId;
                    totalUse[user]['count'] =   data.stats[x].count;
                    console.log(totalUse[user]['count']);
                }
            }
            console.log(totalUse[1]['count']);
        });
    </script>
```

This line is giving me grief: `totalUse[user]['count'] =   data.stats[x].count;`
I know that `data.stats[x].count;` contains data but it comes out as undefined when I do `console.log(totalUse[user]['count']);`.

Comment: Do you have an example of the JSON you get back?

Comment: "I know that `data.stats[x].count;` contains data but it comes out as undefined." -- If the value is undefined, then what you "know" is wrong. Either count is undefined, stats does not have an index x, stats is null/undefined, or data is null/undefined.

Comment: {
   "stats":[
      {
         "userId":13,
         "user":"AM Mobile",
         "service":"total",
         "month":"05/2013",
         "count":19694
      },
      {
         "userId":13,
         "user":"AM Mobile",
         "service":"total",
         "month":"06/2013",
         "count":4008
      },

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of:

```
totalUse[user]          =   data.stats[x].userId;
totalUse[user]['count'] =   data.stats[x].count;
```

try :

`totalUse[user] = { count :   data.stats[x].count };`

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
if (totalUse[user]){ // yes it does have it
    totalUse[user].count += data.stats[x].count;
}else{
    totalUse[user] = {
        userId: user,
        count: data.stats[x].count
    };
}
```

If you want to save both the userID and count in each element of `totalUse`, you have to put them in different properties of the object. You can't assign the userID directly to the array element.

Comment: Thank you for helping me understand. I really appreciate you taking the time to answer my question accurately.